# How to Download Attachment that is an Excel file?

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I want to download attachments from email going to a specific folder. I wrote a VBA code and set a rule for emails going in that folder.

They're all xlsx. Been processing them manually for months, and it's always the same file.

When it downloads the attachment, it saves it as a "File" Type, not xlsx. If I open it, it is all random nonsense.

> ¬Ia‹YéÎÞé}yý¶ª;ßëÖëê—zõ^CBš¥Î¹]U]u·ÿ~ÿzoÝGôÉñÉñ!8„w1uÒä

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim strFileType As String
    Dim DtString As String
    Dim SName As String
    Dim File_Name As String
    Dim Full_Path As String
    
    saveFolder = "\\path\path\path\path\Path\"
    
    strFileType = ".xlsx"
    DtString = Format(Now(), "mm-dd")
    SName = itm.SenderName
    File_Name = DtString & "_" & SName
    Full_Path = saveFolder & "\" & File_Name
    
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile Full_Path
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
         
End Sub
```

I tried adding ".xslx" at the end, I tried opening an instance of Excel, opening the file, save and close.

I tried saving it as a Txt file.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) on the `objAtt.SaveAsFile` instruction, run the code, then inspect the value of `Full_Path` (hover the mouse over the variable, or bring up the *locals* toolwindow, or Ctrl+G and `?Full_Path`) - is it what you expect it to be? Looking at your code it seems you understand everything you need to fix this already: seems learning to use the debugger would be more beneficial than anything else.

Comment: Are your attachments actually xlsx files?  If you save them manually from Outlook can you open them normally in excel?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, they're all xslx. Been processing them manually for months, and it's always the same file, so the file itself is good to go.

Comment: saveFolder already has a terminating backslash, so no need to add it again here: `Full_Path = saveFolder & "\" & File_Name`

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
Full_Path = saveFolder & "\" & File_Name
```

to:

```
Full_Path = saveFolder & "\" & File_Name & strFileType
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the attachment file name.

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName
```

Comment: This is how I had it originally, and it works. So thank you for reminding me. But I changed it since the file name is usually too long, and I use that file for importing to an ERP system, and it does not take long names.

Comment: You can try to retrieve the short file name using the GetShortPathName Windows API function  - see https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/401394-code-convert-path-name-short-dos-style.html

Answer (score 0):

*Should be*

> ```
> File_Name = DtString & "_" & SName & strFileType
> ```

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim strFileType As String
    Dim DtString As String
    Dim SName As String
    Dim File_Name As String
    Dim Full_Path As String

    saveFolder = "\\path\path\path\path\Path\"

    strFileType = ".xlsx"

    DtString = Format(Now(), "mm-dd")

    SName = itm.SenderName

    File_Name = DtString & "_" & SName & strFileType

    Full_Path = saveFolder & File_Name
    Debug.Print Full_Path ' print on Immediate Window

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile Full_Path
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```